# Combining :not() with :nth-child(2n+1) on table tr

Tags: html, css

I have a striped table. In between the striped rows im looking to insert a row with an alphabet letter like A,B,C etc. Like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="letter">
        <td colspan="3">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text col 1</td>
        <td>Some text col 2</td>
        <td>Some text col 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody
```

I want this row to be ignored in terms of assigning the stripe on each second row.

Figured I could combine `:not` and `:nth-child(2n+1)` but the `.letter` row still seems to count when assigning the stripe (background-color).

```
tr:not(.letter):nth-child(2n+1)
{
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

[Codepen with example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOYKXK)

Comment: That's right, `nth-child` doesn't know or care about classes. There are many questions here on SO about this situation, but no elegant answers. In this case, you could do something with `tr.letter ~ tr:nth-child..` or put each run of tr's in their own tbody.